# Unable to view the database created in hive when connecting from tableau.

Tags: hive, hiveql

I created a sample database in hive and some sample tables in it.when I am connecting to Hive from my BI tool 'Tableau'I am unable to view the databases that are created.Only the defualt database is shown.
Could anyone help me with the issue so that I can access the newly created database in Tableau.

Thank You,
Divya Teja Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Make sure that you are calling your hive server connection from the same directory (or referencing the same metastore) as the one in which you created the database/tables.

Second: When you open up the Cloudera Hadoop Connection, you should be able to see your database under "Step 4: Select a schema on the server" Click the magnifying glass.